# How do I control the way the cropping tool works in Photoshop CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I'd like to set the behavior of the cropping tool.

I want it to define cropping areas based on...

- A fixed, numerical set of pixel dimensions.
- A given proportion, e.g., a 9 by 12 area of arbitrary size.
- Free size and proportion -- wherever I release the mouse button.

Where can I set that for the cropping tool?

---

UPDATE / CLARIFICATION

The marquee tool provides this menu, circled below...

[image]

But the cropping tool doesn't offer a menu like that...

[image]

Does the cropping tool does have these three modes like the marquee tool? If so, where do I set that? How do I tell the cropping tool which mode to use?

Comment: Not sure if it got lost in the noise, but on the second image in Jack's post he mentions using Marquee tool and then `Image` -> `Crop` to achieve the same effect as the crop tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to what i understood,you can follow these steps crop your document in defined px or inch.
there are two methods of doing this i prefer using marquee tool with fixed size,please check SS,i tried to explain a bit :| sorry for these rude images i was running out of time.

this one is from crop tool it self you can set values according to your need.
[image]

this second one is based on marquee tool which i prefer.

[image]

i know these images look so bad :| just want to clear your confusion,hope you got some clue :|

Answer (score 4):

I hope I understand your question right...

To set a fixed numerical crop area, you type in the dimensions you'd like in the top toolbar after you've selected the crop tool. (This is the toolbar that resides underneath the file/edit/image menus).

Then, when you click and drag the crop box it will keep to those dimensions, and the final crop will be that size.

I don't quite understand your second bullet, and as for the thirds bullet, well, that's how the crop tool naturally operates, isn't it?